# Which properties are false for an empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

An empty set is closed, open, bounded, convex... All of that is **vacuously** true.

I wonder which properties are false for empty set?

Comment: It's false that the empty set is nonempty.

Comment: what other properties are you considering?

Comment: @GrahamKemp, any! Hopefully, something less trivial than "nonempty" :)

Comment: Any statement that starts "for all $x \in X$..." will be true if $X=\emptyset$. Any statement that starts "there exists $x \in X$..." will be false if $X=\emptyset$.

Comment: Not exactly "false", but $\bigcap \emptyset$ is the set of all sets, which doesn't really exist.

Comment: @Hyperion There is no such set which contains every set.

Comment: @kccu, that's a really interesting direction! Thank you!

Comment: As an example, the empty set is not a [star domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain).

Comment: The empty set is NOT closed, NOT open, unbounded, NOT convex....

Comment: @N.S. In the definition of a topology the empty set is required to be closed and open. And it IS convex.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Well, the OP is asking for FALSE statements about the empty set, I was listing some ;)

Comment: @N.S. OK then..................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key distinction has to do with quantifiers: is the property in question **universal** or **existential**?

Any property of the form "Every element is [stuff]" is trivially satisfied by the emptyset since the emptyset has no elements which could *fail* to be [stuff].

Conversely, any property of the form "Some element is [stuff]" is trivially false of the emptyset.

Note that "for all" and "there exists" are dual to each other: the negation of a universal statement is an existential statement, and conversely. So any property referring to elements only will be either trivially true of the emptyset or trivially false of the emptyset.

Comment: Note @kccu's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3227808/which-properties-are-false-for-an-empty-set#comment6640676_3227808) to a similar effect.